# Is there any way to use custom typescript interface/type for a react component from node_modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, node-modules, antd

I want to add one more value to size prop on the button component from antd.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button as AntButton } from 'antd'
import { ButtonProps as AntButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button'
import { SizeType } from 'antd/lib/config-provider/SizeContext'

import styles from './_.module.css'

type CustomSizeType = SizeType | 'xlarge'

interface Props extends AntButtonProps {
  size?: CustomSizeType
}

// component wrapper for button
```

This gives me the following error

```
Types of property 'size' are incompatible.
    Type 'CustomSizeType' is not assignable to type 'SizeType'.
      Type '"xlarge"' is not assignable to type 'SizeType'
```